# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of linear transformation $A: M_{nxn} \to M_{nxn}$ defined as $A(X)=X^T$.

I understand that $X$ looks like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} && x_{12} && ... && x_{1n} \\ 
x_{21} && x_{22} && ... && x_{2n} \\ 
...    && ...    && ... && \\
x_{n1} && x_{n2} && ... && x_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}

but I don't understand how I am supposed to proceed or get the solution. I would really appreciate some help, thanks.
I know a similar question has already been posted, but the answer there is not helpful to me. There the OP wanted to find the determinant, which could eventually lead me to my eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I just don't understand their step by step procedure.

Comment: You need to find for what matrices $X$ it's possible to have $X^T = \lambda X$ for some scalar $\lambda$. It might help to start with the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ cases if you don't see what to do.

Comment: @user49640 okay, could you explain a bit how I would do that? I am just really confused, because the matrix elements are unknown..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the determinant of the linear transformation $L(A)=A^T$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237044/find-the-determinant-of-the-linear-transformation-la-at-from-mathbbrn)

Comment: You could start with a matrix $X = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c& d}$ and see what has to happen in order to have $X^T = \lambda X$ for some scalar $\lambda$. It would be possible to go straight to the answer, but I think one will learn more if one tries playing around with this first. You'll get equations in $a, b, c, d$ and $\lambda$, and you can solve the system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if, and only if, $X^T=\lambda X$. This is equivalent to saying that$$x_{ji}=\lambda x_{ij},\;\forall 1\le i,j\le n.$$ Now we observe that $$X=(X^T)^T=\lambda X^T.$$ This is equivalent to saying $$x_{ij}=\lambda x_{ji},\;\forall 1\le i,j\le n.$$ So now we have the following equality $$x_{ij}=\lambda ^2x_{ij},\;\forall 1\le i,j\le n.$$
Clearly this is only satisfied if either $\lambda=\pm1$ or $x_{ij}=0\;\forall 1\le i,y\le n$ however the latter results in $X=0$ which is not an eigenvector. Therefore we have that the only eigenvalues are $\lambda =\pm1$. $\lambda =1$ gives us $x_{ij}=x_{ji}\,\forall 1\le i,j\le n,$ i.e., $X$ (an eigenvector) is a symmetric matrix. $\lambda =-1$ forces $x_{ii}=0,\,\forall 1\le i\le n$ and $x_{ij}=-x_{ji},\,\forall 1\le i,j\le n,\,i\ne j$.

---

The explanation of one way to find the geometric multiplicities is as follows.

First recall that the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue, $\lambda$, of $A$ is defined as the dimension of the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$, denoted $E_A(\lambda)$. If $X\in E_A(-1)$ then we know that the diagonal entries of $X$ must be zero. Observe also that if we choose an entry $x_{ij}$ of $X$ then this forces $x_{ji}=-x_{ij},\,i\ne j,$ as explained above. This leaves us with only $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ choices for the entries of $X$ and hence tells us (in a naïve sort of sense) that $$dim(E_A(-1))=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$ (Check this for yourself).

Now for $\lambda =1$. This is a very similar situation to $\lambda =-1$. If $X\in E_A(1)$ and if we make a choice for $x_{ij}$ then this forces $x_{ji}=x_{ij},\,i\ne j,\,$ (since $X$ is a symmetric matrix) and as shown this gives us $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ choices for non-diagonal entries of our matrix $X$. The difference here is that we are permitted non-zero entries on the diagonal of $X$ so this gives us a further $n$ choices for entries of $X$ and therefore we have that $$dim(E_A(1))=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Can't $\lambda $ also be $-1$? Wouldn't  $A $ then have another eigen vector?

Comment: Yes you are correct and thank you for pointing that out. With $\lambda =-1$ the resulting eigenvector $X$ would have zeros down the diagonal and then all the other entries of $X$ would have to satisfy $x_{ij}=-x_{ji}\,\forall 1\le i,j\le n,\,i\ne j.$

Comment: okay, what would the multiplicities of these eigenvalues be? Can $A$ have both $-1$ and $1$ as eigenvalues at the same time?

Comment: Yes of course, $A$ has both eigenvalues simultaneously. $\lambda =-1$ has geometric multiplicity of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $\lambda =1$ has geometric multiplicity of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$ I believe the algebraic multiplicities are the same but someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay, can you just please explain how you got those multiplicities? Thanks

Comment: I'll add the explanation of this into my previous answer.

Answer (score 4):

Really big hint: $A^2=I$

So $\lambda^2=\dots$

Comment: $\lambda ^2=1$ I guess.. how do you know that $A^2 = I$?

Comment: @ivana14, because the transpose of the transpose is the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix such that the entry at the $i$-th column and $j$-th row is equal to $1$ and all other entries are equal to $0$. Consider the basis of $M_{n\times n}$ whose elements are the matrices $E_{i,i}$ as well as the matrices $E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}$ and $E_{ij}-E_{j,i}$ ($j\neq i$). Each vector of this basis is an eigenvector of $A$. To be more precise, $A\bigl(E_{i,i}\bigr)=A_{i,i}$, $A\bigl(E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}\bigr)=E_{j,i}+E_{i,j}=E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}$, and $A\bigl(E_{i,j}-E_{j,i}\bigr)=E_{j,i}-E_{i,j}=-\bigl(E_{i,j}-E_{j,i}\bigr)$.